# What do you call the covered area of the drive-through at a bank? Not really a Porte Cochere, banks are typically open on 3 sides

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The drive-through area that has a solid roof over it and not just an awning or canopy extruding from the side of the building.  Typically seen at bank branches that have more than one drive-up teller lane.

I have found "Carport" and "Port Cochere" but neither seems to fit the actual use as described above.

Comment: Are you talking about the place where drive-thru service is actually performed? Do you have a photograph or other image? Is this different to the covered area in a gas station, or the covered pick-up/drop-off area outside a hotel?

Comment: Architecturally, it is still a canopy.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this photograph](https://www.dreamstime.com/bank-drive-thru-banking-station-sunny-day-there-atm-machines-places-to-send-deposit-teller-brick-commercial-image198282574)

Comment: I'm a university-educated, native English speaker in my 40s and I've never heard "Port Cochere".

Comment: *Porte cochère* is French, so needs the *e* on *porte*; the accent might be dropped when borrowed into English.  But the sense in American English is rather different to the original meaning in [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porte_coch%C3%A8re) and to the very rare use as an architectural term in British English. (@KarlKnechtel)

Comment: @ChrisH it was already clear to me that this is a French loanword (loan-term?) but that doesn't change the fact that I haven't heard it before :)

Answer (score 4):

The area under the canopy and including the canopy is called a service island. That's what local ordinances use to describe the area.

> Service island sign means a sign mounted permanently on, under, or otherwise mounted on a service island canopy.
> https://library.municode.com/FL/dunedin/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=SPBLADECO_CH105DEST_DIV2DEST_105-29.1DE

This works for ATMs.
https://blog.qualitydatasystems.com/how-much-does-an-island-atm-cost

Comment: This is probably the closest that one can get to what the OP seeks, but, as I understand it, although a service island **may** be covered, it is not a part of its definition that it is covered. An uncovered service island would still be a service island, wouldn't it? The OP seems to want a term that stands specifically for a covered service island (including its cover).

Answer (score 2):

Canopy

triple or three-lane drive-through teller **canopy**, for example

like here:

[image: canopy]

Austin Mohawk bank teller canopy

[canopy](https://www.austinmohawk.com/products/canopies/view/285-bank-teller-canopy)

Also like this:

[image: canopy]

canopy is also used for fast food joints.

DSA Signage
2321 East Gladwick St Rancho // Dominguez, CA // 90220 // 310-537-5000

Comment: The question is seeking a word for the whole **covered area** rather than just the cover that covers it, while I would think that *canopy* (in so far as it is used in this context at all) would normally be understood to refer only to the cover. Would you really say 'I needed some cash, so I drove my car into the canopy of the XY Bank'?

Comment: @jsw29 Of course, you would say I went to the ATM in the drive-through window or lane. But this could be about architecture or design. There is no "whole covered area". It is used. Look at the construction and design sites I posted. Gees.